# Synology CloudStation log?

Tags: nas, synology

Sometimes my CloudStation takes forever to do something, that I think should be quite quick. Sometimes it says "Processing" and some file name, but I don't know if it is updating my client (downloading) or the server (uploading). I would like to look into what it is actually doing. Is there a log file that I can read?

I am interested in all the following:

- log on Linux client
- log on Windows client
- log on Synology NAS

I have not been able to find anything like that.

Comment: I would check on their technical forums.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did write there, and haven't gotten a reply.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you find the log files in
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\CloudStation\log`

On your Synology NAS at least in DSM version 5.1-5004 in the `main menu` -> `protocoll center` (use the filter).

Under linux I don't know but probably in the `/var/log` folder.

Answer (score 1):

In DSM in Cloudstation Settings, it is possible to set some options for logging.

[image]

Apparently it uses a database for logging, and when looking around in the file system, the database is a PostgreSQL database, located in `Volume1/@database`. However, it is not possible for me to figure out this database. In particular, I would just like to know what files are being updated at a point in time.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux clients the logs are in:
~/.CloudStation/log    (~ is the user home directory)
On the server the logs are in:
/volume1/@cloudstation/log/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be possible to see a log on Linux, but it is broken on my computer. Please comment if it works/does not for you.

There is a folder `/opt/Synology/CloudStation/log`. On my computer it only contains of file, `launcher.debug` which does not tell about what has been synced/uploaded/downloaded.

If right clicking in the Process Bar on the CloudStation icon, then choosing Settings, then "Download history", it is just an empty list.

[image]

And then there is the small window, when clicking the CloudStation icon -> Recently modified files. It shows only file names, not the folder, no size, not whether downloaded or uploaded or synced, and it moves too fast. Pretty useless.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Hans' answer above, ~/.CloudStation/log is also the location on MacOS / OSX.  A useful command is:
`tail -f daemon.log | grep ERROR`