# How to wipe all CloudStation data and start from scratch

Tags: nas, factory-defaults

I believe my CloudStation somehow got corrupted. At least it never seized updating, and I can't tell if it was the client applying changes to the server, or the server applying changes to the client (see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/832172/synology-cloudstation-log)).

Now how do I get back to a situation where everything just works?

This is my idea:

1. Uninstall CloudStation on clients
2. On the server, make a manual copy of the Cloudstation folder, for the specific user
3. Delete all content of this folder
4. On the DSM, go to Cloudstation -> Settings -> Log Delete Rules -> Delete all logs
5. Copy the backup back into the user's Cloudstation folder
6. Reinstall CloudStation on clients

Will that work? Is there a better way?

Comment: What about asking the same question on the Synology forums?

Comment: I'm curious now, so I need to ask. Doesn't it belong here, and if so, why?

Comment: I think you may find a quicker answer posting on a forum that has an audience that's specific to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However I have even worse experience with asking Synology questions there, since I never got an answer to any of my questions. On SuperUser I got at least a couple (of Synology related questions). I think the Synology forum, like many forums on the web, are so messy that questions just drown.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to disconnect the client PC's (uninstall is probably easiest). Then delete the users from the Synology (after backing up any data if you want to keep it though the data is more likely to be up to date on the clients than the server?).

Then go and reset the cloud storage settings on the Synology.

I think that should work. Not actually had to do this so proceed with caution. Not much can go wrong if you have copies of the data somewhere.

Don't think you will need to worry about the logs as you've deleted the users and the user data.

Reread the Synology documentation to make sure you are following the recommended practices. Then start with new users then install the clients. Obviously, you will want to install the clients one at a time and start with a single shared folder before proceeding.

Also note that if you turn on full indexing, it can take DAYS at very high CPU levels. Take it slow and steady.